# SQLite updating certain columns of a table with a click of a "add" button error and crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

My app is suppose to have the users enter an amount and click the "add" button to add transactions into the "transactions" table and the amount that the user entered will also update the amount of the specified category (a certain column/field) in the "spendings" table.

The code for the add button is below :

```
public void AddTransactions (final int temp_position) {
        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int temp_id = 0;

                Cursor transactionlatestid = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(temp_position);
                if (transactionlatestid.getCount() == 0) {
                    temp_id = 1;
                } else {
                    transactionlatestid.moveToFirst();
                    temp_id = transactionlatestid.getInt(0);
                    temp_id += 1;
                }

                String transaction_id = String.valueOf(temp_id);

                String flightposition_id = String.valueOf(temp_position);

                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertTransactionData(amount.getText().toString(), category, note.getText().toString(), transaction_id, flightposition_id);


                if (isInserted = true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "Transaction Inserted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clearText();
                    temp += 1;
                    getLatestAmount(temp_position, category);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "Transaction not Inserted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

The method "getLatestAmount" is called when a transaction is successfully added. This method is to get the amount of the specified category that is currently already existing in the "spendings" table. For example, if the category is "Food and Drinks", this method will return the value in that column "foodndrinks" from the "spendings" table and then the "updateAddTotalExpenses" is called later.

The code is below :

```
public void getLatestAmount (int temp_position, String category) {
        temp_position += 1;
        String id = String.valueOf(temp_position);
        String temp_category = "";
        double amountfromdb = 5.00 ;

        if (category == "Food and Drinks")
        {
            temp_category = "foodndrinks";
        }
        else if (category == "Travel")
        {
            temp_category = "travel";
        }
        else if (category == "Shopping")
        {
            temp_category = "shopping";
        }
        else if (category == "Entertainment")
        {
            temp_category = "entertainment";
        }
        else if (category == "Others")
        {
            temp_category = "others";
        }

        Cursor latestamount = myDb.getLatestAmount(id, temp_category);
        if (latestamount.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "No amount found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            latestamount.moveToFirst();
            amountfromdb = latestamount.getDouble(0);
            updateAddTotalExpenses(id ,temp_category, amountfromdb);
        }
    }
```

This method "updateAddTotalExpenses" is used to add the sum of amount that is in the "spendings" table of the specified category and the amount that is entered by the user, and then update the newest amount into the specified "category" in the "spendings" table.

```
    public void updateAddTotalExpenses(String temp_position,String temp_category, double newestamount) {

        double amount_tobeadded = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
        newestamount += amount_tobeadded;

        if (category == "Food and Drinks") {
            myDb.updateFnDData(temp_position, temp_category, newestamount);
        }

        sTracker.RefreshAllSpendings();
    }
```

The "spending" table code in my DatabaseHelper.class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper :-

```
    private static final String SPENDING_TABLE = "spendings";
    private static final String ID_SPENDING = "id";
    private static final String BUDGET = "budget";
    private static final String TOTAL_EXPENSES = "total_expenses";
    private static final String FOODNDRINKS = "foodndrinks";
    private static final String TRAVEL = "travel";
    private static final String SHOPPING = "shopping";
    private static final String ENTERTAINMENT = "entertainment";
    private static final String OTHERS = "others";
    private static final String BALANCE = "balance";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SPENDING_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, BUDGET DOUBLE, TOTAL_EXPENSES DOUBLE, FOODNDRINKS DOUBLE, TRAVEL DOUBLE, SHOPPING DOUBLE, ENTERTAINMENT DOUBLE, OTHERS DOUBLE, BALANCE DOUBLE)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TRANSACTION_TABLE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, AMOUNT DOUBLE NOT NULL, CATEGORY TEXT NOT NULL, NOTE TEXT, TRANSACTION_ID TEXT NOT NULL, FLIGHT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (FLIGHT_ID) REFERENCES FLIGHT_TABLE(id) )");
    }
```

The method below is in the DatabaseHelper.class which is called from the Main class to get the amount of the specified category in the "spendings" table.

```
    public Cursor getLatestAmount(String id, String category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor latestamount = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+category+" FROM spendings WHERE id =" +id , null);
        return latestamount;
    }
```

The method below "updateFnDData" is in the DatabaseHelper.class which is called from the Main class to update the amount of the specified category with the newestamount (old amount + new amount entered by user)

***Note : For now I only have a single method to update a column in the "spendings" table which is the "foodndrinks" column as I just want to test whether my concept and code is correct before I add more.

```
    public boolean updateFnDData(String id, String category, double newamount) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        db.update(SPENDING_TABLE, contentValues, "id = ?"+"category = ?", new String[] {id});

        return true;

    }
```

Below is the logcat which appears when I try to click the "add" button after entering an amount into the `EditText` box, the transaction is successfully added into the "transactions" table but the amount in the "spendings" table of the specified category is not updated.especially this two methods `"getLatestAmount"` and `"updateFnDData"` in the `DatabaseHelper.class`.

```
   --------- beginning of crash
10-23 22:07:23.419 4070-4070/project.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: project.myapplication, PID: 4070
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
        at project.myapplication.AddExpenses.updateAddTotalExpenses(AddExpenses.java:231)
        at project.myapplication.AddExpenses.getLatestAmount(AddExpenses.java:225)
        at project.myapplication.AddExpenses$3.onClick(AddExpenses.java:155)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1):

In these lines of `updateFnDData()`:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
db.update(SPENDING_TABLE, contentValues, "id = ?"+"category = ?", new String[] {id});
```

you pass empty `contentValues` to the `update()` method.  
 
Before `db.update()` set the `contentValues` like this:  
`contentValues.put(columnname, newamount);`  
replace `columnname` with the name of the column to be updated.   
**Edit** in SPENDING_TABLE where you want the update there is no `category` column. Maybe you should change the `WHERE` part of the `update()` method to something like: 
`"id = ? AND something = ?"`  
 
**Edit2** change to this in `updateFnDData()`:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("foodndrinks", newamount);
db.update(SPENDING_TABLE, contentValues, "id = ?", new String[] {id});
```

Comment: Added ur suggestions ! But my app still crashes and the logcat shows the exact same "error" code as I posted in my question ! :(

Comment: See my edited answer. What is the category in `"id = ?"+"category = ?"`?

Comment: I see what you mean there ! But the reason I put "category = ?" when I don't have a column "category" in my "spendings" table is because I wanted this update method to be able to update "Food and Drinks","Travel", "Shopping" and etc columns without having to create a update method for each column that I want to update. And the "category" variable was supposed to represent the column name. So if I pass "foodndrinks" in the "category" variable and into the update() method I want the method to update the "foodndrinks" column if u get what I mean.

Comment: any idea what I should change or modify in order to work the way I want it to? I deleted the +"category = ?" from that statement but still same error :(

Comment: For now I want to update the "foodndrinks" column from the spendings table once I add a transaction. But if possible I want this method to work in a way that it can update a certain column, for example if I want to update the "travel" column in the spendings table.Then, I will pass in the "travel" as a String in the "category" variable and it will update accordingly to the "category" variable.

Comment: There is a category parameter in the method but not another variable. If you know the value of the "travel" column because you will update it, then set the variable you want to this value without executing any updates. The truth is I don't really understand what you want to achieve. For the time try to solve the update problem and if it works then try to push it further.

Comment: Understood sir. But now I just want to update the "foodndrinks" column by adding the amount that the user entered with the amount existing in the "foodndrinks" column and replace it with the latest sum amount, but I still get the same error and do not know how to proceed.

Comment: This line: `double amount_tobeadded = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());` maybe gives the error if the text is not a valid number, so enclose it inside a try/catch and try again.

Comment: Yes Sir, I've enclosed it inside a try/catch and it has been the problem all this while. What should I use instead to convert string into double?

Comment: If the values you enter are valid numbers and they are giving error then the problem that I would think of is the decimal separator being `.` instead of `,` or vice versa and not being recognized as such. I can't think of anything else

Comment: But even when I enter whole numbers such as "30" it still gives me the same error.... Or would it be better if I send you my whole project instead?

Comment: Set a breakpoint to this line `amountfromdb = latestamount.getDouble(0);` and check if an error occurs or if the value returned is valid.

Comment: I found the error, its because of the "clearText()" being before the calling of the other method ! Thanks a lot !